# Strange JUnit/Google Endpoint test result

Tags: java, google-app-engine, android-studio, junit, objectify

I have the below test method to test the creation of the Partner entity in Objectify datastore.

I got the DuplicateRecordException as excepted, but when I try to retrieve the entity (any entity in that Class) and I got a null.  Any idea what I missed?

NOTE: I launched the local API explorer to test the createPartner() method and it just fine.

```
@Test
public void  testCreatePartner(){
    try {
        Partner p = createPartner(instID, displayName, new Text(aboutMe));
        createPartner(instID, displayName, newText(aboutMe));

        assertNull(p);

    } catch (DuplicateRecordException | MissingIDException | FailToSaveRecordException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        log.severe("======> "+e.getMessage());
        Partner q = OfyController.ofy().load().type(Partner.class).first().now();

        if (q!=null) {
            log.info("------>>" + q.getDisplayName());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

I also had this:

```
new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig().setDefaultHighRepJobPolicyUnappliedJobPercentage(100)
```

I change 100 to 1 and it worked.

Comment: You probably want `.setApplyAllHighRepJobPolicy()` in tests